# how to integrate an image trasformer to alfresco

Tags: ocr, alfresco, tesseract

I'm using a tesseract transformer in Alfresco in order to make a TIFF image searchable. I've found many tutorials about this which i've tried on my Alfresco but it's not working.

here is the sample [tesseract integration](https://shahpritesh.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/search-in-image-using-tesseract-in-alfresco/)

i'm on Alfresco Enterprise v5.0.2

it seems that the transformer is not integrated , i upload tiff image but no result in searching words.
How can I check if the transformer is applied ?

Comment: Have you added some debugging trace in your code ? How have you checked if the transformer is called ? You can also set to debug the level of logging for the package org.alfresco.repo.content.transform

Comment: Alfresco 5.0.2 only bundles Apache Tika 1.6. [Tesseract support was added in Tika in Tika 1.7](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-93). So, you'll either need to do your own backport, or ask Alfresco to make one for you

Comment: @Gagravarr If I am not wrong, it seems to be that the he is using an external tool executed on the command line and so it does not need to use the embedded Tika.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I think the OP wants to use the Alfresco link to Tika, to then use the Tika link to Tesseract. That Tika link only came in with Tika 1.7, so either they need to upgrade their version of Tika, or manually add an Alfresco-Tesseract transformer that skips Tika

Comment: @Gagravarr the article that he followed was written in 2013. I have not checked that the solution described in that article is correct, but it seems to me that it simply execute a batch command.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALLING TESSTRACT OCR:
Download tesseract from (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)
and install it by double click on tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe.

After installing tesseract in system "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR" path will be created with installed Tesseract OCR.

CHANGES MADE TO BE DONE IN ALFRESCO
Files to be added.
1)OCR.bat2)ocrpng-transform-context.xml3)ocrjpeg-transform-context.xml4)ocrtiff-transform-context.xml5)alfresco-tesseract-search.jar6)ocrtransform.log
1)OCR.bat

```
REM to see what happens
echo from %1 to %2 >>C:\tmp\ocrtransform.log


copy /Y %1 C:\TMP\%~n1%~x1

REM  call tesseract and redirect output to $TARGET
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" C:\TMP\%~n1%~x1 %~d2%~p2%~n2 -l eng
del C:\TMP\%~n1%~x1
```

this batch script is to placed in your alfresco in this path "C:\Alfresco"

this batch script will send the the uploaded file to Tesseract ocr to do actual OCR, copies the log to the ocrtransform.log,Tesseract OCR send content to alfresco and we can change the actual language which in the above file default given eng, and we can give multiple languages to this.

These are the transformation xml will be added in "C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension"

2)ocrpng-transform-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans default-lazy-init="false" default-autowire="no" default-dependency-check="none">
  <bean id="transformer.worker.ocr.jpeg" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="mimetypeService">
      <ref bean="mimetypeService" />
    </property>
    <property name="checkCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
  <value>/C</value>
  <value>dir c:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transformCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
  <value>/C</value>
  <value>C:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
                <value>"${source}"</value>
                <value>"${target}"</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1,2</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="explicitTransformations">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
          <property name="sourceMimetype">
            <value>image/png</value>
          </property>
          <property name="targetMimetype">
            <value>text/plain</value>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="transformer.ocr.jpeg" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer" parent="baseContentTransformer" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="worker">
      <ref bean="transformer.worker.ocr.jpeg" />
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

3)ocrjpeg-transform-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans default-lazy-init="false" default-autowire="no" default-dependency-check="none">
  <bean id="transformer.worker.ocr.tiff" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="mimetypeService">
      <ref bean="mimetypeService" />
    </property>
    <property name="checkCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
  <value>/C</value>
  <value>dir c:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transformCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
    <value>/C</value>
    <value>C:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
                <value>"${source}"</value>
                <value>"${target}"</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1,2</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="explicitTransformations">
      <list>

        <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
          <property name="sourceMimetype">
            <value>image/jpeg</value>
          </property>
          <property name="targetMimetype">
            <value>text/plain</value>
          </property>
        </bean>


      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="transformer.ocr.tiff" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer" parent="baseContentTransformer" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="worker">
      <ref bean="transformer.worker.ocr.tiff" />
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

4)ocrtiff-transform-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans default-lazy-init="false" default-autowire="no" default-dependency-check="none">
  <bean id="transformer.worker.ocr.tiff" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="mimetypeService">
      <ref bean="mimetypeService" />
    </property>
    <property name="checkCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
  <value>/C</value>
  <value>dir c:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="transformCommand">
      <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
        <property name="commandsAndArguments">
          <map>
            <entry key="Windows.*">
              <list>
                <value>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</value>
  <value>/C</value>
  <value>C:\Alfresco\ocr.bat</value>
                <value>"${source}"</value>
                <value>"${target}"</value>
              </list>
            </entry>
          </map>
        </property>
        <property name="errorCodes">
          <value>1,2</value>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="explicitTransformations">
      <list>

        <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
          <property name="sourceMimetype">
            <value>image/tiff</value>
          </property>
          <property name="targetMimetype">
            <value>text/plain</value>
          </property>
        </bean>


      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="transformer.ocr.tiff" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer" parent="baseContentTransformer" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="worker">
      <ref bean="transformer.worker.ocr.tiff" />
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

these all are transformations files we can write any no. based on type format of files which want to do OCR with Tesseract.

5)alfresco-tesseract-search.jar
Downolad this jar from this link([https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B94FD2QmPSJCNHpuUVlicW95UjA/edit)][1]
and place this jar in this path "C:\Alfresco\tomcat\lib".
6)ocrtransform.log
create an empty file name with ocrtransform.log in "C:\TMP"

after that restart the alfresco

then upload a image formatted files, content of the image will be indexed in alfresco so we can search the content of the file.